# Defining java collections in basic English

Tags: java, collections

Can someone give a very brief definition of what a collection is in java as if you were describing it to someone with little or no programming experience?
And also defining some types of collections like sets, lists and maps?
Thanks

Comment: Read a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html). "A collection represents a group of objects, known as its *elements*."

Answer (score 1):

A bag, with different restrictions.

- List = Allowing duplicates. Ordered, items have a position(index).
- Set = Not allowing duplicates
- Map = Each item has a key which you can use to fetch it from the bag
  easily instead of having to look through the bag.

If you want more information just Google it, it is not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

**Collection**

- A `Collection` is a bunch of related elements.  These items may or may not be ordered. There may or may not be duplicate elements.

  This is the most abstracted data structure. Anytime you have a bunch of related elements in one place, its a `Collection`.

**List**

- A `List` is an ordered `Collection`. A `List` can contain duplicates.

**Set**

- A `Set` is an unordered `Collection`. A `Set` only contains distinct elements, meaning it cannot contain duplicates.

**Map**

- A `Map` is an unordered `Collection` where one element is used to access another element.  Think of a math expression like, y=x.  That would yield a slope where every value on the y axis is mapped to a value on the x axis. A map can't contain duplicate `keys`.  In my previous example, the values on the y-axis would be keys.

Answer (score 1):

I would describe collections as objects that can hold multiple other objects. Collections can be ordered and unordered. They may or may not allow duplicates. The differences between collections are as follows:

- Lists hold objects with an order; duplicates are allowed.
- Hash Sets hold objects without an order; duplicates are prohibited.
- Linked hash sets hold objects with a predictable iteration order; duplicates are prohibited.
- Tree sets hold objects with user-specified ordering; duplicates are prohibited.
- Hash maps keep pairs of key and value objects, with no ordering and no duplicates on keys.
- Linked hash maps keep pairs of key and value objects, with predictable ordering and no duplicates on keys.
- Tree maps keep pairs of key and value objects, with user-specified ordering among keys and no duplicates on keys.

Maps allow access to values given a value of its corresponding key.

Answer (score 0):

A Java `Collection` is just a "collection" (guess what) of objects of a certain type. You can add, remove and search items in the collection &co. Additionally, a collection has some properties, which varies among the different interfaces:

## List

A list is an ordered collection, where each element in the collection has a number associated, 0 (included) to n (excluded), where n is the number of elements in the collection.

That number is called the "key", because you can get an element by specifying that *key*.

This is the "basic" type of collection, holding a row of elements together.

## Map

A map is just like a list, but it's not ordered and the elements can have any object as key (for example, a `String`), not just an integer. This is great if the key has a meaning for you.

## Set

A set is like a list, but unordered and without keys (you can't ask for "element number 3"). Additionally, it does not allow for the same element to be included twice, just like a set in Maths.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be difficult to define collections without using the word in its own definition, but I'll give it a try.

In programming, variables refer to one thing at a time (or nothing).  For example,

```
int x = 5;
char letter = 'g';
```

Even with objects, variables still point to only one object at a time (or null):

```
Object o = new Object();
```

When you need to represent multiple "things", you can use a collection, which holds multiple things in it.

```
Collection<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
numbers.add(2);
numbers.add(3);
```

`numbers` now refers to 2 and 3.

There are different types of collections built in to the Java libraries: lists, sets and maps.

A `List` is a collection which holds items in the order in which they are added.  You can reference an item, or element, in the list by its position which corresponds to where you inserted it.

A `Set` is a collection which holds unique items in no particular order.  There are types of sets which are sorted (called SortedSet, imagine that!) by some criteria, like sorting numbers numerically.  Some sets have no predictable order (like a HashSet).

A `Map` is a collection which stores key/value pairs, like "x = 5" and "y = 10".  You can retrieve an element by its key which was used when inserting it.  Maps are also generally unsorted, except for certain types.  Keys must be unique.  For example:

```
Map<String, Integer> mapping = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
mapping.put("first key", 20);
mapping.put("second key", 80);
mapping.put("whoa this is a key too!", 8);

System.out.println(mapping.get("whoa this is a key too!"));  // prints 8
```

For more details, see the java docs and look for `Collection`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/